# EMA in the TTR package, when vector length = n, EMA = mean regardless of smoothing ratio (which becomes irrelevant)?

Tags: r

I'm pretty confused on why this works this way.

```
> x <- c(1,2,3)
> EMA <- EMA(x, n=3)
> EMA
[1] NA NA  2
> EMA <- EMA(x, n=3, ratio= .3)
> EMA
[1] NA NA  2
> EMA <- EMA(x, n=2, ratio= .3)
> EMA
[1]   NA 1.50 1.95
> EMA <- EMA(x, n=2)
> EMA
[1]  NA 1.5 2.5
```

So when `n` is equal to the length of the vector, EMA = mean, and smoothing ratio is irrelevant? Not getting this at all.

Answer (score 0):

The first non-NA value will occur at observation `n` and it will be equal to the arithmetic mean of the first `n` observations. The exponential smoothing will begin at this point.

The `ratio` argument specifies the decay, and does not change when the first non-NA observation occurs.

Regardless, exponential smoothing is unstable until you have about 3 times as much data as the smoothing ratio implies. For example, for `n=10` (`ratio=2/(10+1)`), you need about 30 observations before the exponential moving average stabilizes. See the *Warning* and *Examples* sections of `?EMA`.